# Delete line in CSV if two columns not equal

Tags: powershell, csv

I have big CSV Files, here some example of content:

```
Name;Number;Type;AlterName
Prag;1418;2;2012;Prag
Prag;1836;3;2012;Prag
Prag;1836;514;2012;Moscow
...
```

And I need delete the line where is not equal `Name` and `AlterName`.
In this case:

```
Prag;1836;514;2012;Moscow
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check if the fields are equal.

```
Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\input.csv' -Delimiter ';' |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $_.AlterName } |
  Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -Delimiter ';' -NoType
```

Comment: Thank you. But the final file will be created empty. Although I try it with simple data.

Comment: Problem found: diacritics and space :)